# Custom UIAlertView doesn't works?

Tags: ios

[image]I customized UIAlertView (code is mentioned below). It works perfect except if uialertview (custom alert view) is called twice the "**if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])**"part becomes failure. what must be the solution ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'it becomes a failure?'

Comment: Where is the `UIAlertView`? It looks to me that you made a custom "alert" but this is not a `UIAlertView`.

Comment: I think that he's adding these subviews to a an `UIAlertView`, and is simply preparing them in the above methods.

Comment: The problem is not in the code you posted. If the "if" clause for UIImageView is returning false, then it's because you don't have a subview that's an image view.  You need to post the code where you add the subviews. It might help to log the class of the subview before these if clauses to see what the class is.

Comment: if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) is not executed, but if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])  is executed.

Comment: i have uploaded the image. kindly have look on it. "if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])" this one is true for the first time, but for next consecutive alert this one becomes false. what must be the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try either of these instead:

1. You can override drawRect: method. Here's a tutorial on it:

   **Subclass UIAlertView to Customize the Look of an Alert**
   http://joris.kluivers.nl/blog/2009/04/23/subclass-uialertview-to-create-a-custom-alert/
2. You can instead use an alternative to alert view. Here's a nice one:

   https://github.com/gpambrozio/BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets

   (I don't think that overriding show method is the best way to go, but implementing either of the above should be quick and painless.)

Comment: thanks for the hint JRG. i tried overriding drawRect: and it works now